# How Many Circles go Through 3 Distinct Points of $\mathbb{R}^2 $

Tags: geometry

Let $x,y$ and $z$ three distinct points of    $\mathbb{R}^2$.
How many circles go through these 3 points and what's their centre relatively to $x$,$y$ and $z$?

Comment: The perpendicular bisector of a chord of a circle passes through the center of the circle.

Comment: Related: ["General Formula for Equidistant Locus of Three Points"](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1628698/general-formula-for-equidistant-locus-of-three-points/1628713#1628713) (from just a few hours ago)

Answer (score 0):

If all three points are on some straight line, there are no circles going through all three points.

If they are not on one straight line, there is exactly one circle hitting all three point and that is the circumcircle around the triangle $\Delta{xyz}$.