# Complex Number Circumcenter

Tags: complex-numbers

How would I go about finding the formula for the complex number representation (affix) of the circumcenter of $\triangle abc$ given the affixes $a,b,c$?

Comment: I have found http://imgur.com/a/deUzD but I'm not sure how to interpret this and use it to actually compute the circumcenter. I am unfamiliar with this type of mathematics (matrices?)

Comment: See another answer [**here**](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1628698/general-formula-for-equidistant-locus-of-three-points/1628779#1628779)

Comment: Answer posted [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2058832/291201). Voting to close since this is a duplicate of the other question.

Comment: Also take a look here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2122651/derivation-of-formula-for-circumcenter-of-triangle