# Formula for the center of the nine point circle in complex numbers

Tags: geometry, reference-request, complex-numbers

Did some testing with a CAS and found  this cute fact:

Consider three points $a$, $b$, $c$ in the complex plane, and $e$ the center  of the [nine point circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-point_circle) of the triangle $a b c$. Show that

$$e = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{\left| \begin{matrix}
1& a^2 & \bar a \\
1& b^2 & \bar b \\
1& c^2 & \bar c
\end{matrix}\right| } {\left | \begin{matrix} 1 &  a & \bar a \\
1&  b & \bar b \\
1& c & \bar c 
\end{matrix}\right| }$$

This is all probably known,  but haven't seen it before.  Any feedback, or references would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried proving it algebraically? What have you found? I'd start with $\left|\frac{a+b}{2}-e\right| = \left|\frac{b+c}{2}-e\right| = \left|\frac{c+a}{2}-e\right|$ and see what I can get from that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a complete exposition, but I think an approach to a proof might be as follows:

Since the nine-point circle passes through the midpoints of each side, it is the circumscribed circle of the triangle that joins these midpoints, which would have representations $\{\frac{b+c}{2}, \frac{c+a}{2}, \frac{a+b}{2}\}$.  Then we would presumably use the result derived [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481357/finding-center-and-radius-of-circumcircle) to complete the proof.

Comment: That seems like a very useful idea!